# Wrapping a td in a div and opening that div in a JQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page which in one section asks the user to check a box if they'd like more options to select from - the default way the page was displaying that extra information was by adding a td to the page (yes it is a table layout, no I did not build the page that way, it was handed to me like this). I'm trying to wrap that td in a div using jquery .wrap and then immediately display that new div in a dialog box using .dialog. I can get it to work using chrome's console, but putting the code in my js file it no longer works and just displays as a td.

I had to select the td in a roundabout way:

```
if($('#idCustomDIV').length){
    $("#idCustomDIV").parent().attr("ID", "big-repeating-box");
```

so big-repeating-box is the td I'm wrapping in a div like this:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
       $('#big-repeating-box').wrap('<div id="repeating-popup"></div>')
       $('#repeating-popup').dialog();
    }
});
```

I've tried adding a delay before the .wrap, thinking maybe it's trying to wrap the div before it has the id I'm trying to select it by, but that didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would wrapping a `td` with a `div` even be valid HTML?

Comment: I don't see why not. Like I said I get it to do what I want live in the console, for some reason though it doesn't give me the same result when I save the code in my actual js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out this morning. First of all, in response to @Paulie_D I considered the fact that it may not be valid HTML to stick a td in a div - even if it did work. Then I realized instead of trying to grab them element, give it an ID and then do something to it, I could simply grab the element and do to it what I want without changing it's attributes. So I changed my initial code to not grab the td, but rather grab its parent table and I wrapped it in a div and right after put that div I created in the dialog and it worked like a charm.

```
if($('#idCustomDIV').length){
    $("#idCustomDIV").parent().parent().parent().parent().wrap('<div id="repeating-popup"></div>')
    $('#repeating-popup').dialog();
```